# Memory leak in Moq?

Tags: moq

I found this while attempting to find a memory leak in my code.  I kept isolating more and more of my code and still leaking memory.

```
public interface IClient
{
    Task<List<string>> GetNothing();
}

public class Client : IClient
{
    public async Task<List<string>> GetNothing()
    {
        //await Task.Delay(1); // appears to have no effect on memory usage
        return new List<string> { "I am", "Client" };
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    Task<List<string>> DoNothing();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private IClient client;
    public Service(IClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<List<string>> DoNothing()
    {
        return await client.GetNothing();
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class MoqTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Memory_leak_test1()
    {
        IClient client = new Client();
        Service service = new Service(client);

        while (true)
        {
            await service.DoNothing(); // runs indefinitely
        }
    }


    [Test]
    public async Task Memory_leak_test2()
    {
        Mock<IClient> clientMock = new Mock<IClient>();
        clientMock.Setup(x => x.GetNothing()).ReturnsAsync(new List<string> { "I am", "a mock" });
        Service service = new Service(clientMock.Object);

        while (true)
        {
            //create a little busy work in the loop... appears to have no effect
            Guid g = new Guid();
            var z = Math.Sqrt(50670780805d);

            //await Task.Delay(1); // uncomment this line else out of memory in ~ 2 mins.
            await service.DoNothing(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Autofac, Version=4.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.4.7.1\lib\net45\Autofac.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Castle.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Castle.Core.4.2.1\lib\net45\Castle.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions, Version=1.0.500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions.1.0.500-preview2-1-003177\lib\net451\Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.2.1.0-preview1-26216-03\lib\net45\Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.2.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.2.0.2\lib\net461\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.2.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.2.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.2.1.0-preview1-26216-03\lib\net451\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.2.1.0-preview1-final\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Moq, Version=4.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Moq.4.8.2\lib\net45\Moq.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="MySqlConnector, Version=0.38.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d33d3e53aa5f8c92, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\MySqlConnector.0.38.0\lib\net46\MySqlConnector.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.11.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="nunit.framework, Version=3.10.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\NUnit.3.10.1\lib\net45\nunit.framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.2.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Pomelo.JsonObject, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Pomelo.JsonObject.1.1.1\lib\net451\Pomelo.JsonObject.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Why are you ding this?

Comment: As mentioned I was isolating code in my project and kept leaking memory.  Finally isolated the issue to my mocked object.  Am I creating it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Garbage collector just isn't getting the opportunity to collect things. I wrapped this up in a program like this...

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new MoqTests().Memory_leak_test2().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

and watched the memory usage, and like you said, for test1 the memory usage stays absolutely flat. For test2, it just keeps climbing. However, if you add `GC.Collect();` in test2 on the line before `await service.DoNothing();`, then the memory usage stays flat. So it's not leaking memory. (If it was leaking, then the garbage collector wouldn't be able to collect it.) Hope this helps.

Comment: >If it was leaking, then the garbage collector wouldn't be able to collect it.  -   Yup, that's the last word.  Good work!